# When was "emoji" first used?

Tags: etymology, terminology, history, emoticons

*Emoji* is a small digital image or icon used in electronic communication. It is also mentioned as a standardized *emoticon* (emotion + icon) but emojis are usually depicted as pictographs and emoticons are depicted as characters.

Etymology of *emoji*:

> From Japanese 絵文字 emoji (emoji, emoticon), from 絵 e (picture) + 文字 moji (character) [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emoji)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) mentions the creation year of the first emoji:

> The first emoji was created in 1998 or 1999 by Shigetaka Kurita, who was part of the team working on NTT DoCoMo's i-mode mobile internet platform.

But I'm asking when the term "emoji" first used in English language? When it entered technical jargon, did it enter English also? Or did it enter after it was used in Japan for a while?

♥

Comment: One thing that is happening with the word *emoji* is that it was borrowed as a fixed noun no matter the number: it didn’t inflect by adding an *‑s* to make it plural. But as non-technical people catch hold of it, they create the same sort of double-plural as seen in *?paninis* and *?graffitis*, and produce the questionable form *?emojis* as a plural.

Comment: @tchrist Except here it's not a double plural, since _emoji_ itself is simply unspecified for number, unlike _panini_ and _graffiti_ who both have singulars in _-o_.

Comment: Funny, I never knew _emoji_ was a full-blown Japanese word. I've always associated the _ji_ with Japanese 字, but I'd always just assumed it was emo(tive) ji (characters), sort of like _emoticon_. Interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The OED has the first use in English of the word *emoji* in 1997, but I found use of the word in the Latin alphabet in 1991.

Here's part of a 1991 [comp.human-factors Usenet](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.human-factors/Azl4GXul-co/tQwmbHSumv0J) post by Don Norman (author of *The Design of Everyday Things*):

> But who is Yukio Ota?
>
> ---
>   The University of california library lists:
>   1. Japanese signs / Yukio Ota, Osami Sakano, Miwako Ito [editor in charge].
>      Tokyo : Process Architecture Pub. Co., 1983.
>   2. Ota, Yukio.
>        History of ancient China / Ota Yukio, Utsugi Akira, Hori Toshikazu.  Tokyo
>      : Centre for East Asian Cultural Studies. 1974.
>   3. Ota, Yukio, 1939-
>        Pictogram design / Yukio Ota = Pikutoguramu **"emoji"** dezain
>      Shohan.  Tokyo, Japan : Kashiwashobo, 1987.
>
> (The references are only at UCLA and Berkeley, so I can't look at them.)
>
> Tell us more.

Here's the book title at [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/pictogram-design-yukio-ota-pikutoguramu-emoji-dezain/oclc/16710886&referer=brief_results):

> Pictogram design / Yukio Ota = ピクトグラム「絵文字」デザイン /
>   Pictogram design / Yukio Ota = Pikutoguramu "**emoji**" dezain
>   Author: 太田幸夫, 1939- 太田幸夫. 太田幸夫, ; Yukio Ōta
>   Publisher: 柏書房, Tokyo, Japan : Kashiwashobo, 1987.
>   Edition/Format:   Book : English : Shohan

It looks like *Pikutoguramu "emoji" dezain* in the title is just a Latinised version of *ピクトグラム「絵文字」デザイン /*, the English being "Pictogram design". But it may be worth checking the book as it seems to be in English.

And I'm not sure if listing a book title in an English 1991 Usenet post counts as use in English, but it shows the term was in use at least in 1991 (and possibly back to 1987).

Comment: I've sent this to the OED.

Comment: I'm not sure I would count a transliteration of a foreign phrase as a use in English.

Comment: I thought emoji was a combination of katakana and kanji scripts based on emoticon. Here is what I mean: emo, romanized katakana meaning emotion as in emotion in emoticon (emotion + icon), and kanji character ji which means letter or character. So, emoji, as I assumed, is emo + ji where emo (katakana) and ji (kanji). I am surprised to learn e in emoji is: e + moji (picture + character). When it is interpreted this way, where is the emotion in emoji?

Comment: What do you mean by "romanized katakana meaning emotion"?